# Problem with USB adapters and hubs

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, usb, mouse

I am using windows 10 bootcamp in a 2017 macbook pro with touchbar.

I need to connect a cooling base with a USB cable but my macbook only has USB-C, at the same time the cooling base has a mice connected to it. I have a simple OTG adapter (not a hub, just a 1 to 1 adapter) so there shouldn't be any troubles.

But the problem is that the mice which is connected to the cooling base is not recognized by windows. I tried using a hub instead of an adapter and it works perfectly but I really need to use the adapter.

So, what works:

macbook > hub > cooling base > mice

```
    > adapter > mice

    > adapter > cooling base
```

What doesn't work:

macbook > adapter > cooling base > mice

Should be something related to drivers but couldn't find any solution.

Comment: Could you include the make and model of both the OTG and cooling base?

Comment: I initial thought is the OTG is USB 2.0 and the cooling base is USB 3.0.